# Create depth map from 3d points

Tags: matlab, graphics, 3d, computer-vision

I have given 3d points of a scene or a subset of these points comprising one object of the scene. I would like to create a depth image from these points, that is the pixel value in the image encodes the distance of the corresponding 3d point to the camera.

I have found the following similar question

http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/319097

however the answers there do not help me, since I want to use MATLAB. To get the image values is not difficult (e.g. simply compute the distance of each 3d point to the camera's origin), however I do not know how to figure out the corresponding locations in the 2d image.

I could only imagine that you project all 3d points on a plane and bin their positions on the plane in discrete, well, rectangles on the plane. Then you could average the depth value for each bin.
I could however imagine that the result of such a procedure would be a very pixelated image, not being very smooth. 
How would you go about this problem?

Comment: Can you provide a small example showing the format of you 3D data? Are they in an n-by-3 matrix (i.e. a list of XYZ coords)? Your procedure sounds good though, if you want it less pixelated you can consider interpolating (which you can do after projecting). Also if your data are how I think they are, projecting is simply a matter of ignoring the Z values.

Comment: Yes, data is simply a n-by-3 matrix (XYZ coordinates). Ok, in my coordinate system the y-axis is the axis pointing away from the camera. So in my case I would ignore the y-values. The y-values themselves are then the distances from the XZ plane and could be used as depth. Since the camera might be tilted, one could also use a plane orthogonal to the floor plane for the same procedure, I would think.

Comment: If the camera is tilted, I would suggest multiplying by a rotation matrix first to make you Y values equal to the depth you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've corrected for camera tilt (a simple matrix multiplication if you know the angle), you can probably just follow [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html)

```
X = data(:,1);
Y = data(:,1);
Z = data(:,1);

%// This bit requires you to make some choices like the start X and Z, end X and Z and resolution (X and Z) of your desired depth map
[Xi, Zi] = meshgrid(X_start:X_res:X_end, Z_start:Z_res:Z_end);

depth_map = griddata(X,Z,Y,Xi,Zi)
```

Comment: hi! thanks for your answer. I however do have the feeling that griddata will not achieve a desired result. The interpolation almost looks like a polygon where you can not recognize the actual shape of the object anymore. I'd be happy to give an example pointn cloud of an object, if you tell me how I can send you the mat file. I believe one needs some other form of interpolation

Comment: You can link to the file with something like dropbox or google drive. The only suggestion I can make is (a) try a higher resolution (i.e. very low values for `X_res` and `Z_res`) otherwise if that fails then try (b) use quite a low resolution just to get your points on a regular grid (the lowest resolution you can without sacrificing points), then try `interp2` with a different interpolation method such as splines and a high resolution again