# Easiest way to generate depth image/map from 3d model

Tags: graphics, 3d, rendering

I was wondering if anybody knew of an easy, robust way to generate depth images from 3d models (i.e. surface models, vertices with faces), with specifiable camera parameters.

I'd prefer "free" options if possible (e.g. pyOpengl or some open source Java library rather than say matlab).

I believe it is possible with the python blender api ([noted here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45674/synthesize-depth-image-from-3d-model?noredirect=1&lq=1)), but I'm hoping there's an easier way.
Note also that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307057/create-depth-map-from-3d-points) works only for that special case.

Comment: At least for pyopengl, there is nothing that is already pre-built to do this. Is it safe to assume you are basically asking for, given say an obj file, to render a depth texture for a given scene from the camera's perspective? Is this for realtime rendering purposes, or should the output be saved to an image file on the harddrive?

Comment: @user2588654 Yes, exactly. Realtime would be nice, but not necessary for this.

Comment: An answer to this would have been awesome..

Comment: Meshlab does this, but I am afraid one cannot write a script to automate it.

Comment: Any useful answer so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DECA repository in Github. There, in ./demos, I used demo_reconstruct.py code to save the depth image.